# How to sum annual data in a csv of daily data with many years of data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Using a csv of daily data I am trying to find the annual total precipitation for every year. My csv has many years worth of data.

I've tried AnnualMaxPRCP=df3.resample('AS').sum() but this also sums my year column. How can I sum just the Precip column?

```
df = pd.read_csv("Current2.csv")
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Year']=df.Date.dt.year
df['New_date'] = df['Date']

df2=df[df.PRCP!='M']
df3=df2[df2.PRCP!='T']
df3['PRCP']=df3.PRCP.astype('float')

df3=df3.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['New_date']))

AnnualMaxPRCP=df3.resample('AS').sum()
```

Comment: `df3.groupby('Year')['Your columns'].sum()` ?

Comment: When I changed it to that I got this error: "TypeError: an integer is required" so I changed "df3['PRCP']=df3.PRCP.astype('float')" to "df3['PRCP']=df3.PRCP.astype('int')" and tried again but then got this error message: "value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Comment: @MeganMartin, Could you add the few lines of sample data to analyse the data in order to get into correct results.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DatetimeIndex, then you may try the following.

```
df3.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='AS'))['PRCP'].sum()
```